# cannot execute nextval() in a read-only transaction

Tags: postgresql, jpa

Actually we used `@Transactional(readOnly=true)` for some methods but these methods execute nextVal() in some way that is fine for other databases but on Postgres 9.6.3 it results in below error.

```
cannot execute nextval() in a read-only transaction
```

I was going through Postgres Mail logs and found where this error is coming only after 8.4.2 https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/BANLkTik9ikVUU-bznOhZHmLbdEx5fverCw%40mail.gmail.com

Is there any way out there to fix this at DB level.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html

> Advance sequence and return new value

so it changes the value - which can't be done in read only transaction.

**update**

```
set transaction_read_only to on;
```

makes session read only, not just a transaction (which would be the case with `SET LOCAL`)

quoting Craig from your link

> before 
>   9.0, Pg just didn't notice and warn you.

So there was a bug earlier when you were not warned. but nextval did not roll on next value

There's nothing to fix her - either `set transaction_read_only to off` and advance the sequence, or use `currval`. you can have a read only transaction and yet modify data - where's the logic?..

Comment: I understand your point but same works on Oracle and mysql as sequence generation is completely out of transaction, And postgres also states that -a nextval operation is never rolled back;

Comment: Is there a way out to put nextVal from read only transaction scope in postgres??

Comment: very good point - nextval is ok for transaction part, yet it against for "read only". if you `set transaction_read_only to on` you make readonly session, not just transaction. maybe it's not too good naming for setting...

Comment: you cant modify data with `transaction_read_only`. if you just need nextvalue, read current one, but if you need to change the value, you have to turn off `transaction_read_only`